# Recycleview miss anothers components

Tags: android

I have a Recycleview like this:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Swipe to update" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
           android:id="@+id/listNoticiaSwiper"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
              android:id="@+id/noticia_list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:scrollbars="vertical" />
      </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

When I use this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(layoutView, parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder v = new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    };
    return v;
}
```

My view no render my TextView 'Swipe to update'. I use the Google Code Example. I don't have RecyclerView.ViewHolde implementation.

Someone can help-me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this url 
http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example
You have to set many things for RecyclerView